# modify and add string to text file

Tags: python, parsing, txt

I need to find all lines in a txt file that have the string Z0.2 in them and replace them with a new string. Then add a new string “G1” 2 lines down.

Original sample:

```
N1565 Z0.2 F50.192
N1570 X3.0041 Y1.7703
```

Desired output sample:

```
N1565 G0 Z0.2 F50.192
N1570 X3.0041 Y1.7703
N1571 G1
```

This is what I’ve tried so far but I don’t know how to add the G1 on the third line.

```py
# open file in read mode
print("Searching for rapids")
string1 = 'Z0.2 F50.192'

insertline=0
flag=0
file = open("InputFile.txt", "r")
replaced_content = ""
i = 0

# looping through the file
for line in file:

    
    # stripping line break
    line = line.strip()

    #if insertline==i:
    #   new_line = line.replace(line, "\ntest")
    #   print("inserted at line # ", line)
    #   insertline=0
        
    # replacing the text if the string is found
    
    
    if string1 in line:
        new_line = line.replace("Z0.2 F50.192", "G0 Z0.2")
        insertline = i + 2

    
    
    
    else:
        new_line = line

    # concatenate the new string and add an end-line break
    replaced_content = replaced_content + new_line + "\n"

    # Increase loop counter
    i = i + 1
        

    
# close the file
file.close()

# Open file in write mode
write_file = open("OutputFile.txt", "w")

# overwriting the old file contents with the new/replaced content
write_file.write(replaced_content)

# close the file
write_file.close()
print("Rapids have been added")
```

Comment: how about the `Nxxxx` in front of the strings? what's that?

Comment: What are the Nxxx numbers? N1571 is obviously N1570 plus 1 but what if there's already a N1571 column in the file? Is the first token always of the form Nxxx? Could Z0.2 occur anywhere in a line or does it have to match exactly with the second token? Could Z0.2 occur more than once in a file? If so, what then?

Comment: also, you state you want to replace `Z0.2` but in the desired output you don't replace, but you add the `G0` in front of it.

Comment: This is Gcode for a Cnc machine. The Nxxxx are just line numbers. They are auto generated in increments of 5 so there is room to add code manually. Z0.2 can occur anywhere in the line but only once per line. Z0.2 occurs hundreds of times throughout the file do manually changing is not possible. Yes correct I need to add G0 not replace. My biggest problem I’m having is adding the G1 2 lines below the occurrence of z0.2

Answer (score 0):

A toggle boolean is all you need, besides a result list instead of trying to manipulate to original list.

Manipulating a list while you're iterating over it is a clear way to get errors. It's safer to iterate over the input list and generating a new list.

It's also advised to use the `with open(filename)` pattern as shown below. It will make sure the files get closed at an easily identifiable time due to the indentation. See [this](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python) for some explanation.

Also note that I did a search and replace, but if the `G0` needs to be directly after the `Nxxx` then that's easily adjustable to this line:
`result.append(f"{line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)[0]} G0 {line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)[1]}")`
In this case you could also drop `str_replace` variable.

```py
print("Searching for rapids")
str_search = 'Z0.2'
str_replace = f'G0 {str_search}'
str_extra_line = 'N{} G1'

# the method below reads the whole file at once, and closes it.
# using the read().splitlines() method as this will remove the \n characters
with open("InputFile.txt") as infile:
    lines = infile.read().splitlines()


# helper variables
do_stuff = False
n = 0
# resulting list
result = []


for line in lines:
    if str_search in line:
        # simple search and replace on the line itself and toggle do_stuff
        result.append(line.replace(str_search, str_replace))
        # toggle
        do_stuff = True
    elif do_stuff:
        # get the number from the line
        n = int(line.split(' ')[0][1:]) +1
        result.append(line)
        result.append(str_extra_line.format(n))
        # toggle
        do_stuff = False
    else:
        # append the line if above conditionals not met
        result.append(line)

    

# Open file in write mode
with open("OutputFile.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in result:
        outfile.write(f'{line}\n')

print("Rapids have been added")
```

Finally, also note that you could just directly write to the output file instead of using the result variable. This will decrease processing time, as you only have to iterate once.

```py
print("Searching for rapids")
str_search = 'Z0.2'
str_replace = f'G0 {str_search}'
str_extra_line = 'N{} G1\n'

# the method below reads the whole file at once, and closes it.
# using the read().splitlines() method as this will remove the \n characters
with open("InputFile.txt") as infile:
    lines = infile.read().splitlines()


# helper variables
do_stuff = False
n = 0


# Open file in write mode
with open("OutputFile.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        if str_search in line:
            # simple search and replace on the line itself and toggle do_stuff
            outfile.write(f"{line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)[0]} G0 {line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)[1]}\n")
            # outfile.write(line.replace(str_search, str_replace))
            # toggle
            do_stuff = True
        elif do_stuff:
            # get the number from the line
            n = int(line.split(' ')[0][1:]) +1
            outfile.write(f"{line}\n")
            outfile.write(str_extra_line.format(n))
            # toggle
            do_stuff = False
        else:
            # append the line if above conditionals not met
            outfile.write(f"{line}\n")


print("Rapids have been added")
```